# How to help husband change?

Tags: nikah

Since past year I have started following, practicing and observing the proper principles of Islam, which I previously wasn't. But my husband, although a very good man, hasn't yet adopted the same path.

I want my husband to change his current non-Islamic path and illuminate his spirit with the love of Allah, in the same manner as I have.

However being a woman, I can't give orders to him nor will he listen to me. I can only request him, which I am currently doing, but he only agrees to it and never actually acts upon it.

I just want to know, how can I change his current practices? Or at least help him realize the truth of this life.

Answer (score 4):

Walecum assalam sister,

Glad to know that you became close to Allah.

Regarding your husband, you have to first understand that guidance is NOT in our hands. its only Allah, who controls the hearts. So the first thing you have to do is to PRAY to Allah, that Allah may change his heart and bring him close to Him.

2ndly, you have to try to remove all type of Haram actions in your home, specially those acts, which take away blessing, for example, music, picture of living creatures, and try to adopt a life, in accordance with Sunnah of prophet Muhammad. this way, atleast your home will have blessings of Allah in it, which surely affect the hearts.

As he is your husband, usually husbands dislike that her wife teach them something or correct their mistakes. so be careful in that case. try to find the Best suitable situation, where just show him the hadith of prophet Muhammad, about certain situation, or show him verses of Quran, but Never taunt him directly. Just try to give him knowldge first, that what he does not know of. Most people do this mistake that they think that we can stop someone from doing something, and they SHOULD listen. that doesnt happens all the time, because everyone has a certain level of iman, and he has to be taught, based on HIS level, not based on YOUR level. so understand him. and try to show him lessons from islam on regular basis. Show him how mercy of Allah can help their relation. show how islam brings peace in their lives.

Regularly recite verses of Quran in loud voice, so it reaches everywhere in home.

in the end, Do Not foget to pray. as Allah only changes hearts, we dont. our job is only to Convey the message, and that too in best possible way, which does not offends anyone. and dont expect a change suddenly. Change comes, but you have to be patient and keep trying.

May Allah help you in this noble cause.

Allah says in Quran: 16:25

> Invite (all) to the Way of thy Lord with wisdom and beautiful
>   preaching; and argue with them in ways that are best and most gracious

Comment: I totally agree upon your answer. But with a little objection here: `because everyone has a certain level of iman`. These are true words to say, but when followed by `he has to be taught, based on HIS level, not based on YOUR level.` I have to object here, because the level of iman can only be known by God himself, we cannot say or think that one has a higher level of iman than other. What we can say is that one has a better knowledge of islam. I would prefer those words. Thanks for the comprehensive answer though.